# What are the options to use cassandra 2.0.8 in Java

Tags: java, jdbc, cassandra-2.0

I used cassandra-jdbc 1.2.5, but when query for timestamp columns it shows 'AssertError'.
It is due incompatibility of cassandra-jdbc-1.2.5 with cassandra-2.0.8.
It works with cassandra-1.x series.
So I need to know what are other ways to use cassandra in Java with preparedStatement.
I saw some clients like thrift but cannot execute sql type queries.

Answer (score 0):

At this point in time, I don't think there is a JDBC driver that works with Casandra 2.x.  The "casandra-jdbc" driver looks like it has not been touched since April 2013.  There is even an issue in the tracker that says "Doesn't works with Cassandra 2.0" but it hasn't been assigned to anyone.

Unless you intend to do the work yourself (or pay someone else to do it for you), it looks pretty grim.

---

According to this question ([Cassandra Client Java API's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15983190/cassandra-client-java-apis)) there are a number of Java APIs for Casandra that don't involve JDBC.  You would probably be advised to switch to one of these.

There is also a page on the Official Casandra site that lists client drivers:

- [Apache Casandra Client Drivers](http://planetcassandra.org/client-drivers-tools/)